# Bitmap file Integrity/Validity checking to confirm completion of Save Progress

Tags: c#, wpf, image, bitmap, managed

Heyo,
I'm trying to find out if the Save-Progress of a bitmap file is completed, can't use the lock state or UNC Journal for it.. And heres why:

Running a FileSystemWatcher i detect file creations and changes (also folders.. but they are not a problem). Now if i was just expecting copy/move operations this whole thing wouldn't be a problem.. The problem arises when the DCC applications come into play (let's take PhotoShop as an example here).

When you open a file in PS it locks it (so far so good), when you save a file it saves to a temp then does some 'magic' and you got your 'new' file (depending on PS.version and file output format it writes to the file directly without the temp).. Even when using a temp it keeps a constant lock on the file and the Close is only added to the unc journal when you close the file in the application, not after the save is finished..

So you can see my problem here.. In order to process the file further after it has been changed(or created) i need to know if it is in fact a valid, complete bitmap file.
I've been searching and reading for 4 days on this now and thought I'd see if anyone was willing to help me on this.

Here's a shortened version of the Watcher class with only the create and change handlers:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace spacename
{
  public class WatchDog2
  {
    private string RootPath;

    private FileSystemWatcher Watcher;

    // something running in the background chipping away at the cue
    private System.Timers.Timer Clock = new System.Timers.Timer(5000) { AutoReset = true };

    private List<FileSystemEventArgs> FileCheckList = new List<FileSystemEventArgs>();

    private bool CheckLock = false;

    #region Events

    public delegate void OnChangeHandler(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e);
    public delegate void OnRenameHandler(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e);

    public event OnChangeHandler OnFileCreate;
    public event OnChangeHandler OnFolderCreate;

    public event OnChangeHandler OnFileChange;

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// ctor
    /// </summary>
    public WatchDog2(string rootPath, string filter = "*.*")
    {
      RootPath = rootPath;

      var di = new DirectoryInfo(rootPath);

      if (di.Exists)
      {
        Watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(di.FullName, filter);

        Watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.CreationTime | NotifyFilters.LastWrite |
                                NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

        Watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;

        Watcher.InternalBufferSize = 65536; //64kb (max)
      }
      else
      {
        Watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
      }

      Watcher.Created += Watcher_Created;
      Watcher.Changed += Watcher_Changed;

      Clock.Elapsed += Clock_Elapsed;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create Handler
    /// </summary>
    void Watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
      if (Path.HasExtension(e.FullPath))
      {
        if (App.SupportedExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(e.FullPath).ToLower()))
        {
          if (new FileInfo(e.FullPath).Exists)
          {
            FileCheckList.Add(e);

            Clock.Start();
          }
        }
      }
      else
      {
        if (OnFolderCreate != null)
          OnFolderCreate(sender, e);
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Change Handler
    /// </summary>
    void Watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
      if (Path.HasExtension(e.FullPath))
      {
        if (App.SupportedExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(e.FullPath).ToLower()))
        {
          if (new FileInfo(e.FullPath).Exists)
          {
            FileCheckList.Add(e);

            Clock.Start();
          }
        }
      } // no folder change catching
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Queue check
    /// </summary>
    void Clock_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
      if (!CheckLock)
      {
        CheckLock = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < FileCheckList.Count; i++)
        {
          var fi = new FileInfo(FileCheckList[i].FullPath);

          if (fi.Exists)
          {
            if (fi.Length > 0) //add propper checks for bitmap validity
            {
              switch (FileCheckList[i].ChangeType)
              {
                case WatcherChangeTypes.Created:
                  if (OnFileCreate != null)
                    OnFileCreate(null, FileCheckList[i]);
                  break;

                case WatcherChangeTypes.Changed:
                  if (OnFileChange != null)
                    OnFileChange(null, FileCheckList[i]);
                  break;
              }
            }
          }
          else // if save was aborted
          {
            FileCheckList.RemoveAt(i);
          }
        }
        CheckLock = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Almost forgot.. I'm doing this in the context of a WPF application.

thx for taking the time :)